# do we save oracle ref cursor result in any file like txt or xls from sql terminal

Tags: oracle

i am running my procedure using help pf ref cursor like

```
SQL> variable rcq refcursor;
SQL> DECLARE
amount NUMBER;
BEGIN
Getresults('null',1,1,1,1,1,1,1,40,1,' 
','NameWithDates',amount,:rcq);
dbms_output.put_line(amount);
END;
/  
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rcq
```

do we save this result any xls file or (txt file in correct format)

Answer (score 0):

txt:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat txt.sql
set heading off termout off echo off
variable rcq refcursor;
begin
  open :rcq for select 'HELLO' as column1, 'WORLD' as column2 from dual;
end;
/
spool result.txt
print :rcq
spool off
exit
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus -S bp/bp @txt.sql
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat result.txt

HELLO WORLD
```

csv (12.2 and later):

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat result.csv
"HELLO","WORLD"

[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat txt.sql
set heading off termout off echo off
variable rcq refcursor;
begin
  open :rcq for select 'HELLO' as column1, 'WORLD' as column2 from dual;
end;
/
spool result.txt
print :rcq
spool off
exit
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus -S bp/bp @csv.sql
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat result.csv
"HELLO","WORLD"
```

Microsoft Excel of LibreOffice Calc or whatever you use can save .csv as .xls.